# Unable to update p2 repository with Eclipse 2019-12 & JDK 11

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, p2, eclipse-gmf

Error screenshot: [Error message while updating P2 repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM9LL.png)

After building the product with JDK 11 on Eclipse 2019-12, failed to update p2 repo due to org.apache.batik.util.gui 1.6.

Problem:
Latest org.apache.batik.util.gui: 1.6 version
Latest org.apache.batik.util: 1.11 version

Due to the version mismatch issue, unable to update p2.

Eclipse Link: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-12/201912181000/

GMF tooling Link: https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/gmf-tooling/updates/releases-3.3.1a/

pom.xml

```
<profile>
      <id>2019-12-release</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <eclipse.repository>https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-12/201912181000/</eclipse.repository>
      </properties>
    </profile>


  </profiles>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>eclipse-repository</id>
      <layout>p2</layout>
      <url>${eclipse.repository}</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>org.eclipse.swtbot.updatesite</id>
      <layout>p2</layout>
      <url>http://download.eclipse.org/technology/swtbot/releases/latest/</url>
    </repository>


     <repository>
      <id>org.eclipse.runtime.tooling</id>
      <layout>p2</layout>
      <url>https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/gmf-tooling/updates/releases-3.3.1a/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Please let me know how do I resolve this issue.
Without this, we can't upgrade our app (JDK 11 compatible).

Comment: You say it _"failed to update p2 repo"_, but the error log says _"Cannot complete the install because..."_. Your `pom.xml` seems to be uncomplete and what does this file have to do with the issue?

Comment: No, my build was successful. Getting an en error saying **missing requirement: batik gui utilities 1.9.1.v 20190730-1743 (org.apache.batik.util.gui 1.9.1.v20190730-1743) requires 'bundle org.apache.batik.util [1.9.1,1.9.2)' but it could not be found**   while eclipse > help > "check for the updates"  From the build repository file(p2 update)

Comment: So it failed on _Help > Check for Updates_, but it does not _"failed to update p2 repo"_, right? If so, please correct your question. In this case, in _Window > Preferences: Install > Available Software Sites_ there is no update sites (p2 repositories or old style update sites) containing `bundle org.apache.batik.util` of the required version. Where is the `pom.xml` file from, why is it incomplete and what does this have to do with the issue? Please give a step-by-step instruction to reproduce this issue.

Comment: My question is absolutely correct. Help > "Check for Updates" takes my own product build p2 repository which is failing.

Comment: _Check for Updates_ takes all(!) in the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ checked updates sites. Is there only one update site checked? Really? Is or does contain your product _System Trace Tools_ and if yes, of which version? Please improve your question instead of adding comments. I guess you mean that updating _from_ a repo failed, not that it failed _to_ update an existing repo, right? And according to the error log, you do not have a version mismatch, but a missing plug-in/bundle (each plug-in/bundle has its own version).

Comment: Reproducible Steps: 
+++++++++++++++ 
Step-1: Build the product on JDK 11 & Eclipse 2019-12 Step-2: Open the product and go to product's help > Install's new softwares > Manage... > add the directory of p2 repository( from the newly created build folder p2 repository) > Reload > Finish Step-3: Go to product's help > click on Check for Updates The error due to org.apache.batik.util.gui(latest:1.6v) version mismatch with org.apache.batik.util(latest 1.11v).